# How do I make a particular word in a UILabel selectable (Swift 2.0)?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, nsattributedstring

I have been facing a big issue that probably has a simple solution the entire day. I have a `UILabel` and it contains an `NSAttributedString` in it. I want a particular range in the `UILabel` to be tappable. I don't want any third-party functionality.

Here is my sample code:

```
let str = dict["itemName"] as! NSString
range = string.rangeOfString(dict["itemName"] as! String)!
index = string.startIndex.distanceTo(range.startIndex)
attributedString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: color, range: NSRange(location: index, length: str.length))
```

Comment: Can you provide an example ?

Answer (score 7):

You can use UITextview and add tap gesture to that, instead of taking UILabel.  Here is an example through you can achieve the same result.

```
/* Set Tap gesture on Text view */

UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapResponse:)];
tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[yourTextView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];

- (void) tapResponse:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{

UITextView *textView =  (UITextView *)recognizer.view;
CGPoint location = [recognizer locationInView:textView];

CGPoint position = CGPointMake(location.x, location.y);

//get location in text from textposition at point
UITextPosition *tapPosition = [textView closestPositionToPoint:position];

//fetch the word at this position (or nil, if not available)
UITextRange *textRange = [textView.tokenizer rangeEnclosingPosition:tapPosition withGranularity:UITextGranularityWord inDirection:UITextLayoutDirectionRight];
NSString *tappedWord = [textView textInRange:textRange];

NSLog(@"tapped word : %@", tappedWord);    
}
```

Comment: but i populating values in uitableview cell

Answer (score 1):

```
**ClickableTextView.h**

@protocol ClickableTextViewDelegate <NSObject>

@required
-(void)textview:(UITextView *)clickableTextView clickedText:(NSString *)text;

@end

@interface ClickableTextView : UITextView

@property (weak, nonatomic) id <ClickableTextViewDelegate> tapDelegate;

-(instancetype)initWithDelegate:(id)delegate;

@end


**ClickableTextView.m**

-(void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];

    [self setProperties];
}


-(void)setProperties {

  self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
  self.editable = NO;
  self.scrollEnabled = NO;
  self.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
  self.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeLink;
  self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

  /* Set Tap gesture on Text view */
  UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapResponse:)];
  tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
  [self addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];

}

- (void) tapResponse:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{

UITextView *textView =  (UITextView *)recognizer.view;
CGPoint location = [recognizer locationInView:textView];

CGPoint position = CGPointMake(location.x, location.y);

//get location in text from textposition at point
UITextPosition *tapPosition = [textView closestPositionToPoint:position];

//fetch the word at this position (or nil, if not available)
UITextRange *textRange = [textView.tokenizer rangeEnclosingPosition:tapPosition withGranularity:UITextGranularityWord inDirection:UITextLayoutDirectionRight];
NSString *tappedWord = [textView textInRange:textRange];

NSLog(@"tapped word : %@", tappedWord); 

if(tappedWord) {

    if([self.tapDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(textview:clickedText:)]){
        [self.tapDelegate textview:self clickedText:tappedWord];
    }
 }

}
```

Use this custom class instead of UITextView in your TableViewCell, Then set delegate in your

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

and get the result in delegate method.

```
-(void)textview:(UITextView *)clickableTextView clickedText:(NSString *)text {
}
```

Answer (score -2):

**Swift 2.0:**

Its better to use a UITextView for the purpose.

1 ) Making a TapGesture  and adding to UITextView.
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

```
    let tapGesture: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "tapResponse:")
    tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    sampleTextView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)    
}
```

2) Adding a method to get the selected word.

```
func tapResponse(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let location: CGPoint = recognizer.locationInView(sampleTextView)
        let position: CGPoint = CGPointMake(location.x, location.y)
        let tapPosition: UITextPosition = sampleTextView.closestPositionToPoint(position)!
        let textRange: UITextRange = sampleTextView.tokenizer.rangeEnclosingPosition(tapPosition, withGranularity: .Word, inDirection: 1)!

        let tappedWord: String = sampleTextView.textInRange(textRange)!
        print("tapped word : %@", tappedWord)
    }
```

Comment: Asked for UILabel, not UITextView